# I am trying Odd Even linked list programming problem on Leet code, I am leetcode so I am unable to identify what this error is about

Tags: c++, runtime-error

this is my code

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* oddEvenList(ListNode* head) {
        ListNode* odd=head;
        ListNode* even=odd->next;
        ListNode* evenStart = even;
        
        while(odd->next!=NULL &&  even->next!=NULL)
        {
            odd->next = even->next;
            odd=odd->next;
            even=odd->next;
            even=even->next;
        }
        
        odd->next=evenStart;
        
        return head;
    }
};
```

and is showing error
`Line 18: Char 41: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:27:41`

Take a look at this screen shot

[image]

Comment: In such case loop will break so there is no way that NULL will be assigned to it

Comment: Effectively. I guess it would be much simpler to create and return a new list, instead of trying to modify the existing one. You should also include in your post the declaration of `ListNode`.

Comment: Have You tried this problem before?

Comment: It has to be done in O (1) space complexity

Comment: I have not tried this one exactly, but by experience I know that performing this kind of manipulation on linked list is really tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first few lines are assuming that the list has at least two elements.
This is your first problem.

If you fix that, note that all you know when you enter the loop body is that `odd->next!=NULL &&  even->next!=NULL`.
On the first iteration, this means that the list has at least three elements.

Let's draw a list and see what happens.
"o" and "e" are `odd` and `even`, and the curly brace is the boundary to the unknown part of the list, which might not exist:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> { 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...
o    e

odd->next = even->next

+---------+
|         V
1    2 -> 3 -> { 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...
o    e

odd = odd->next

+---------+
|         V
1    2 -> 3 -> { 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...
     e    o         

even = odd->next

+---------+
|         V
1    2 -> 3 -> { 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...
          o      e
```

Oops...

```
even = even->next

+---------+
|         V
1    2 -> 3 -> { 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...
          o           e
```

Double oops.

Work out the solution using pen(cil) and paper first.
It's by far the best method to solve (and debug) pointer manipulation problems.
I won't give you a solution, because how much fun would that be?

Comment: yeah thanx I got it. I just came here to correct that, and then ur solution was there

Answer (score 0):

Error: You are trying to access the 'next' data member of a NULL pointer of type ListNode.
Solution: You should check if(even!=NULL) then condition(even->next)
take example 1,2,3,4
Iterations:

1. odd -> 1, odd->next -> 2, even -> 2, even->next -> 3
2. odd -> 3, odd->next -> 4, even -> NULL
   now if you check odd->next!=NULL is true but even->next will throw the error.